# numerical range of Normal operator

Tags: operator-theory

If $A$ is normal then closure of numerical range is the convex hull of spectrum of $A$?

I am reading book byPeter Rosenthal on "Introduction to Operators on the Hilbert Hardy space".
showing the convex hull of spectrum is contained in closure of numerical range part is done by me.
But i am getting the idea to show closure of numerical range is contained in convex hull of spectrum.
book smention its enough to show that every closed half plane in $C$ that contain spectrum of A contain W(A) also. I am trying to figure this out for few days, not able to get it.
Any hint and suggestion.

Comment: This question is a near-duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1013753/spectral-measures-numerical-range (although the OP there expressly assumes familiarity with spectral measures, and you do not, and you specifically ask for an argument based on half-spaces, when the other OP does not [although an answer does take this approach to deduce the result for normal $A$ from the result for self-adjoint $A$]).  Do the answers to this other question help? If not, can you refine the question to clarify what you know and what you have tried?

Comment: i have done this question on my own. every closed half plane that contain convex hull of spectrum of A should contain Numerical range of A. By rotation and traslation it was enough to show that if convex hull of spectrum lies in right half plane$(Re\ge0)$ then numerical range also lies in Right half plane.

Comment: main idea was that every closed convex set in $R^n$(in our case convex hull spectrum of A) can be written as intersection of closed half plane.

Comment: If your solution is different from how it was approached via spectral measures in the other question, feel free to post an answer to your own question! (I can think of a relatively "low-tech" approach, but it still uses the continuous functional calculus., or at least the spectral mapping theorem and equality of the norm and spectral radius for normal elements.) A similar sometimes handy fact: [a *compact* convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the intersection of all closed balls that contain it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3833628/compact-convex-sets-as-intersection-of-balls).